# Second monitor doesn't get signal if highest resolution is set after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I have two monitors connected to PC DisplayPort using DisplayPort-DVI converter. Samsung SyncMaster EX2220 and B2240. Ubuntu 16.04. Videocard is Intel® Haswell Desktop

Problem that second monitor can't work on highest resolution 1680x1050 - it loses signal immediately when I set it. It works only when I set 1440x900 (second in list) or below.

What is wrong? First monitor correctly works at maximum resolution (1920x1080).

Everything worked before upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I have two monitors, one with 1680*1050, and the other 1920*1200. After I updated my system from 14.04 to 16.04, the monitor with high resolution didn't work in its recommended resolution unless set with a lower resolution.

After searching and testing for two hours, I have it solved:

1) set the second monitor with lower resolution (in your case, 1440*900) so that it can work instead of losing signal.

2) turn the other monitor (your first monitor) off in Displays panel.

3) set the current working monitor (your second monitor) back to its maximum resolution (in your case, 1680 * 1050)

4) turn the other monitor on in Displays panel.

I have nvidia-364 installed in my system.

Hope that can help!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on Kubuntu. The solution by zjyin made things worse for me though, all my monitors went dark. To make them work again I had to find where Kubuntu stores information on enabled displays. None of the xrandr, display.xml etc... solutions offered by the net worked for me.
The file I had to edit is in this folder:
~/.local/share/kscreen
it is a json file, I could set my old monitor to enabled there.